# Running a Node script after deployment?

Tags: deployment, continuous-integration, vercel

Is there a post-deploy hook or any other way to run a Node script after deployment on Vercel?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Vercel's webhooks with your Git provider to run a Node script after your Vercel deployment has finished. This example will use GitHub Actions, but you can use any of [the other supported Git providers](https://vercel.com/docs/concepts/git#supported-git-providers).

## Configure a GitHub Action

1. Connect your Git repository to your project. For new projects, you can [follow these docs](https://vercel.com/docs/concepts/git#deploying-a-git-repository). For existing projects, visit your Git configuration in the Settings tab of your project dashboard.
2. Create a GitHub workflow in .github/workflows with the following:

```
# Using Playwright but you may use your E2E framework of choice
name: Playwright Tests

on:
  deployment_status:
    
  run-e2es:
    if: github.event_name == 'deployment_status' && github.event.deployment_status.state == 'success'
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
    - name: Install dependencies
      run: npm ci && npx playwright install --with-deps
    - name: Run tests
        run: npx playwright test
          env:
              BASE_URL: ${{ github.event.deployment_status.environment_url }}
```

Credits: [official documentation](https://vercel.com/guides/how-can-i-run-end-to-end-tests-after-my-vercel-preview-deployment)

Comment: Note that we now recommend using `environment_url` instead of `target_url` for setting `BASE_URL`. We updated our documentation accordingly.